# Flask Fonts not Updating

Tags: html, css, flask

As the title says I've got my style.css and inside of my style.css ive

```
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
```

If I load my page normally (opening my main html file) it shows the new font, however when I attempt to start render_template and host the webpage on localhost using flask it refuses to show the font. Any idea what causes this.

Comment: Make sure your browser is not caching the style.css files. Follow these instructions to disable cache when google chrome developer tools is open: https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Comment: thank you, smh didn't even realize that was a thing

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented this code:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

in your html page?

And have you added your CSS file with this syntax in your html page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/main.css')}}">`?
```